# Add copy of rows in a dataframe based on a column

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have the following data frame

```
  df
  a b c
1 a 3 0
2 b 4 1
3 c 3 0
```

how do I get the following output in which the rows of the original data frame are cloned as often as the number in column b indicates?

This is the desired output:

```
   df2
   a b c
 1 a 3 0
 2 a 3 0
 3 a 3 0
 4 b 4 1
 5 b 4 1
 6 b 4 1
 7 b 4 1
 8 c 3 0
 9 c 3 0
10 c 3 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d[rep(seq_len(nrow(d)), d$b),]
    a b c
1   a 3 0
1.1 a 3 0
1.2 a 3 0
2   b 4 1
2.1 b 4 1
2.2 b 4 1
2.3 b 4 1
3   c 3 0
3.1 c 3 0
3.2 c 3 0
```